# Count daily tasks based on timestamp field?

Tags: count, abap, cds

I have an Issue while using COUNT with DISTINCT on TIMESTAMP field. Below is my CDS view please help.
I want to put COUNT on ConfirmedDate field.

```
 @AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZXEWMIWT'
 @AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
 @AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
 @AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
 @EndUserText.label: 'Interface View for Warehouse Task detail'
 @OData.publish: true
// I* type:ddls

define view ZXEWMI_WT as select from /scwm/ordim_c as ORDIM_C {
    key ORDIM_C.lgnum as WarehouseNo,
    @UI.selectionField: [{ position: 1 }]
    @UI.lineItem: [{ position : 1 }]
    ORDIM_C.processor as Processor,
    @UI.lineItem: [{ position : 2 }]
    //count(distinct ORDIM_C.confirmed_at) as sum_wt

    **tstmp_to_dats( ORDIM_C.confirmed_at,
    abap_system_timezone( $session.client,'NULL' ),
    $session.client,
    'NULL' ) as ConfirmedDate**

}where processor <> '' 
group by lgnum, processor, confirmed_at;
```

Comment: `I have an Issue` and what is your issue?

Comment: On ConfirmedDate field I need to put count with distinct and it is not accepting that expression... this cds is to show count of picks per day by user...

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT here, I have no EWM by my side, but I assume `confirmed_at` is a timestamp field, so there will be no two tasks in the exact same second/millisecond. Please, give your table lines and expected output, and also `/scwm/ordim_c` table definition

Comment: > "so there will be no two tasks in the exact same second/millisecond"

Why do you think so? Unless there's a primary key or unique constraint this is definitly possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like you have millisecond-accurate timestamps in the field `ORDIM_C.confirmed_at`, but you want to group the results by day.

Unfortunately `GROUP BY` only allows you to group by columns from the input table(s)/view(s). It can not be used on calculated columns.

But what you can do is first create a separate CDS view which gives you the fields of the table /scwm/ordim_c with the timestamp converted to a date and then query that view.

View 1:

```
define view Z_ORDIM_C_WITH_DAY as 
select from /scwm/ordim_c as ORDIM_C {
    key ORDIM_C.lgnum as WarehouseNo,
    ORDIM_C.processor as Processor,
    tstmp_to_dats( ORDIM_C.confirmed_at,
    abap_system_timezone( $session.client,'NULL' ),
    $session.client,
    'NULL' ) as ConfirmedDate    
}
```

View 2:

```
define view ZXEWMI_WT as 
select from Z_ORDIM_C_WITH_DAY {
    key WarehouseNo,
    @UI.selectionField: [{ position: 1 }]
    @UI.lineItem: [{ position : 1 }]
    Processor,
    @UI.lineItem: [{ position : 2 }]
    count( * ) as sum_wt
    ConfirmedDate    
}
where processor <> ''
group by WarehouseNo, Processor, ConfirmedDate;
```